# vm machine access and how to show commands of physical machine information with host name

Tags: virtualbox

My server Model : `HP Prolian DL380 G6`.

The server is a physical machine with 5 vm machine

I've access to VM machine only (I don't have any access to my physical machine)

How can I show any information about the host machine (e.g. hostname , ip address or link)?

Comment: I understand English is not the native language for most of us. However, please try to write the question in a way we can understand, using punctuation and *not* shouting in the title. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get details about the `host machine` you need to access it.

The `Virtual Machine` model assume that the `VM` is not aware of the host.

In specific cases the host might allow the VM some minimal access (e.g. `VMWare tools` allows `shared folder` between the host and the guest)

Comment: VM machine ubuntu 16.04.1 i hope just helpfull command exeucted my vm machine show my physical machine name it is possible